# My checkbox values are calculating on unchecking instead of checking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

The below is my code. I want to calculate the value of checked checkbox. I want the functionality like,When I select '#selectall' checkbox, it is selecting all checkboxes and calculating its value. But in this code it is calculating values on unchecking the '#selectall' checkbox . How can I fix this issue?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {


    // Select all
    $('#selecctall').click(function (event) { //on click 
        if (this.checked) { // check select status
            $('.checkbox1').each(function () { //loop through each checkbox
                this.checked = true; //select all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"               
            });
        } else {
            $('.checkbox1').each(function () { //loop through each checkbox
                this.checked = false; //deselect all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"                       
            });
        }
    });

});

//Addition for checked value
$('input').click(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
    console.log(sum);
    $("#sum").html(sum);
});

//popover
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.pop').popover({
        content: "Other Expenses 200 <br> Other Expenses 200 <br>Other Expenses 200 <br> ",
        html: true,
        placement: "right",
        trigger: "focus"
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
        <td align="center">2</td>
        <td align="center">2007 / 00006</td>
        <td align="center">Yousef</td>
        <td align="center">GR5 / A</td>
        <td align="right">0.000</td>
        <td align="right">1000.000
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox5" id="checkbox5" class="checkbox1" value="1000">
        </td>
        <td align="right">1000.000
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox8" id="checkbox8" class="checkbox1" value="1000">
        </td>
        <td align="right">1000.000
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox11" id="checkbox11" class="checkbox1" value="1000">
        </td>
        <td align="right"><strong> 3000.000</strong>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">3</td>
        <td align="center">2012 / 00058</td>
        <td align="center">Ghalia</td>
        <td align="center">KG2 / C</td>
        <td align="right">0.000</td>
        <td align="right">0700.000
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox6" id="checkbox6" class="checkbox1" value="700">
        </td>
        <td align="right">0700.000
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox9" id="checkbox9" class="checkbox1" value="700">
        </td>
        <td align="right">0700.000
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox12" id="checkbox12" class="checkbox1" value="700">
        </td>
        <td align="right"><strong> 2100.000</strong>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" class="hide-xs">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center" class="hide-xs">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center" class="hide-xs">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center" class="hide-xs">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right" class="hide-xs">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right" class="total"><strong>3100.000
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox14" id="checkbox14" class="checkbox1" value="0">
                        </strong>

        </td>
        <td align="right" class="total"><strong>3100.000
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox15" id="checkbox15" class="checkbox1" value="0">
                        </strong>

        </td>
        <td align="right" class="total"><strong>3100.000
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox16" id="checkbox16" class="checkbox1" value="0">
                        </strong>

        </td>
        <td align="right" class="total"><strong> 9300.000
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox13" id="selecctall"  value="0">
                        </strong>

        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Maybe a jsfiddle example would help us to get the problem...

Comment: check my answer, i pasted your code on jsfiddle and gave you a link

Comment: ok... now seriously... your KD 10400 is your SELECTALL item here. you see in my example (on fiddle) that the "selectall" item is working fine don't you ? ...

Comment: When you click on your 3100 item, it does nothing. It does not check any other input, and displays 0 BECAUSE THE 3100 INPUT VALUE IS 0. When you check your selectall item, it checks all items, and then makes the calculation so that the sum of all items (3x1000 + 3x700 + 3x0) is 5100.

Comment: it is working properly in fiddle but not working in my code. I did it before , but now it is not working that is the real problem i have been facing now :)

Comment: FINALLY! So the problem is not in the code you posted here (not in my fiddle!) but on the code you use on your "original" webpage... there is something different. Maybe the jquery version, maybe in code, idk... cannot help further without "real" code...

Comment: I checked it! you should check this : http://jsfiddle.net/ze7wt8qk/1/     I pasted your page code there and only removed your "popover" part. It works fine... problem is somewhere else. I did not copy the header, etc... you should check the console on page load, check the jquery version, at this point, I cannot help further...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Finally I found the problem it was because of I closed the $(document).ready(function() before the  execution 

    $(document).ready(function () {


        // Select all
        $('#selecctall').click(function (event) { //on click 
            if (this.checked) { // check select status
                $('.checkbox1').each(function () { //loop through each checkbox
                    this.checked = true; //select all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"               
                });
            } else {
                $('.checkbox1').each(function () { //loop through each checkbox
                    this.checked = false; //deselect all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"                       
                });
            }
        });

    **** // actually i closed the function here this should be at the end 

    //Addition for checked value
    $('input').click(function () {
        var sum = 0;
        $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
            sum += Number($(this).val());
        });
        console.log(sum);
        $("#sum").html(sum);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.pop').popover({content: "Other Expenses 200 <br> Other Expenses 200 <br>Other Expenses 200 <br> ", html: true, placement: "right", trigger: "focus"}); 
});
```

and copy/paste your code to jsfiddle.net

Everything seems to work... idk where your problem is... your code is working on check & uncheck... !

http://jsfiddle.net/sgvwczjq/1/

Comment: Check the console log, the problem is the value being calculated when the checkbox is not checked. When checked, the console logs `0` when unchecked, it logs `5100`. It's meant to be the other way around.

Comment: Ok : when you click on your "selectall" element, it checks all inputs. Your total inputs sum is 5100, so it sounds logical... you have inputs with value="0", all your "strong tag items" are value 0 ...